# WMI Win32_BaseBoard SerialNumber is empty

Tags: .net, wmi

How to get mainboard serialnumber in .NET?
Win32_BaseBoard.SerialNumber returns an empty string.
any other ways?

note: i'm using windows 7 ultimate x64

Answer (score 1):

What are you really looking for ?

In my case `Win32_BaseBoard.SerialNumber` gives the same result as `win32_bios.SerialNumber`, or `Win32_ComputerSystemProduct.IdentifyingNumber`.

You can find the processor ID with `Win32_Processor.Win32_Processor`.

Comment: I have all three of them empty (Win32_BaseBoard.SerialNumber, win32_bios.SerialNumber and Win32_ComputerSystemProduct.IdentifyingNumber).

Answer (score 0):

It works on my Dell motherboard.  Depending on the manufacturer, you may get different results--they may not even be exposing this to WMI.

You can look at the various fields which are populated using [WMI Explorer](http://www.ks-soft.net/hostmon.eng/wmi/index.htm).

Answer (score 0):

I had to reverse-engineer some protocol that uses Win32_BaseBoard/SerialNumber property.
With earlier versions of VirtualBox it was < empty > in WMI Explorer, but now it is "0".
So, yes it is vendor-dependent.

Moreover, there could or could not exist an instance of Win32_BaseBoard, in my case the software inserted a pre-defined constant if the WMI object could not get instantiated.

The most hassle-free method is to query it using command-line:

> wmic BaseBoard Get SerialNumber